# What does the $\partial$ notation means, in tensor analysis?

Tags: matrices, notation, partial-derivative, tensors, index-notation

I have seen in a lot of introductory texts in Tensor analysis (Arfken & Weber's *Mathematical Methods*, for example). The last one i saw [here (Unfortunately, this text is only avaliable in portuguese)](http://professor.ufrgs.br/rgaelzer/files/fismat_tensors.pdf)  (the author uses the notation in page 216) is that if you have a matrix equation between two vectors (in this example is a rotation matrix):
$$x'_i = L_{ij}x_j$$
Then, you can write
$$L_{ij} = \frac{\partial x'_i}{\partial x_j}$$
This, for me, doesn't seems like a partial derivative. If it is, then why and how? If it is not, then what it is?

Comment: pretty sure it's partial derivative

Comment: Could you please explain it's meaning? Also, why it is a *partial* derivative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed a partial derivative.

For example, you could ask the question "if I use a different set of three coordinates $x',y',z'$ to describe a point in space which in the old coordinates was $(x,y,z)$, and then I change $x$ to some $x+\delta x$, how do each of $x',y',z'$ change?  Notice that in this question, I change $x$ keeping $y$ and $z$ fixed; thus the partial derivative.

(What I said describes in fact a covariant tensor; the relation you give describes a contravariant tensor, but the idea is the same.)

In the case of a specific rotation, these nine partial derivatives form a (constant) matrix $L_{ij}$ but for different types of transformations, the
transformation could easily depend on where you are in space.